# Detect Application Start

Tags: android, startup

How can I detect the start of my application from a completely terminated stated (as if the user went to Manage Applications and forced stopped the app)? I don't mean like a first-time start up when the user first installed the app nor do I mean just in an `Activity` by using `onStart()` or `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but [`Application.onCreate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onCreate%28%29) will be called when the application is starting, before any other application objects have been created. So you could use that to detect when an app is started from a non-running state.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to detect when your app is "force stopped" from Android settings > apps page, or if the app is killed by another app. In both cases, the UNIX process is killed, and this severs the normal Android lifecycle.

Here's a post from [dianne hackborn](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/xfkfRc-j4cw) on the topic.

Comment: I'm not asking to detect when the app is forced stopped, I want to detect when the app is started from a forced stop.

Comment: @Brian How do you expect to detect if your app is started from a force stop if you cannot detect if your app is force stopped in the first place! (this seems to be what Blattman has pointed out)

Comment: I apologize that my wording isn't very accurate but I simply wanted to see if there was a broadcast or something I could use to detect when an app is started from a non-running state (I used forced stop as an example). I can completely understand why an app wouldn't be able to detect a force stop, but that's not what I'm looking for. Anyway, if this isn't possible, that's alright.